# How to import correctly my function from parent folder

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following layout:

```
/project
    /thomas
        /users
            /src
                code_alpha.py
            /tests
                code_beta.py
```

I tried:

```
/project
    /thomas
        /users
            __init__.py
            /src
                code_alpha.py
            /tests
                code_beta.py
```

with `from users.src import code_alpha`

also tried:

```
 /project
        /thomas
            /users
                __init__.py
                /src
                    code_alpha.py
                    __init__.py

                /tests
                    code_beta.py
```

with `from users.src import code_alpha`

I tried to solve the problem with this [guide](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and some similiar topics here, but could not figure out. Adding the directory to my path did not solve the problem.

edit: updated layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you just run the python script by running the command: `python code_beta.py` in the folder `tests`? If you did, you can create an `__init__.py` in the `tests` and try to run: `python -m users.test.code_beta` in the `thomas` floder (make sure that you have `__init__.py` in the floder `users`, `test`, `src`).

Comment: Yes. Error message: "Unable to import 'users.src'"

Comment: I did this experiment several weeks ago, hope I can help you

Comment: I tried like you said.  I get the error: "/usr/bin/python: No module named users.tests"   Im surprised that python imports from other folders are a real pain in the ass...I have spent hours to solve this...but no result yet.

Comment: Wrong spelling? tests or test ?

Comment: its tests - But i tried both. I did an error in the thread topic instead of "test" its "tests". But nvm that was not the problem :(

Comment: but I try this, it works. Did you run the command using thomas floder as the current wording directory? users.tests must corresponding to you folder name and note that __ is two underscore characters.

Comment: Well, it works now. Thank you very much. I have run the command from the wrong folder.

Comment: I am very glad that I can help you ^^!

Comment: One other thing. I can import it from the thomas folder, but what if I want import it in my code-file test-beta-py?

Comment: I can not find a way to do that. I guess that python will not try to search the ancestor folder of your working directory. So if you run `python -m code_beta` in the tests folder, it reports no module named users.src

Comment: Hm, tomorrow I can ask some python programmer. Maybe he knows a solution. I will respond again.

Comment: Well, there is no really a nice or good solution so far. You have to use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder . But unfortunately it did not work for me. I had to rerange my folders to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `__init__.py` to `somefolder_3`.

Then in `code_beta.py` you will be able to write

`from somefolder_3.somefolder_4 import code_alpha`

Comment: Do i have to delete the other inits? And just keep the init in somefolder_3 ? I tried both and does not work :(